# Pretty Graphics in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a trading strategy summarizer.  The goal is to get something that looks like:

[image]

I can do the python to calculate the values but any thoughts on how to replicate the graphics especially the table.

Comment: This is way, way too broad. Did you try Googling "python graphics"?

Comment: Post the code you have so far and the specific error you're getting or problem you're having.

Comment: Yes I did google it and spent hours finding nothing useful.  As for the code there is no code for the graphics as I am trying to figure out how to do it.  You can assume the data it in Pandas dataframes or numpy.matrices/arrays.  I am really most interested in how to represent the table.  I know that Ipython will auto create simple tables but they are not sufficient as I don't really want an Ipython solution but will take it if it is simple.

Comment: Output the data in csv and import into spreadsheet (Excel/Libre Office) https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: This looks like a job for matplotlib.  http://matplotlib.org/